Why does instantiating a class that relies on an API pull work outside routes but fail inside a POST route in Node.js?
I am using cPanel to deploy my Node.js application and working with CommonJS modules. My app uses a class, PastWeather, which fetches data from an external API.
When I instantiate the class outside any route, it works as expected, and I see the correct response in my terminal. For example:
try {
    const PastWeather = require('./pastWeather.js');
    const testInstance = new PastWeather('GHCND:USC00051547');
    console.log("Test instance created successfully:", testInstance);

    // Call a method from the class
    testInstance.parseData()
        .then(reply => {
            console.log("Parse Data executed successfully:", reply);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error during parseData execution:", error);
        });
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error initializing PastWeather instance:", error);
}

However, when I move this logic inside a POST route like this:
app.post('/getLatandLang', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const PastWeather = require('./pastWeather.js');
        const testInstance = new PastWeather('GHCND:USC00261327');
        console.log("Instance created successfully:", testInstance);

        res.json({
            message: "Instance created successfully",
            testInstance: testInstance.locationID,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in /getLatandLang route:", error);
        res.status(500).json({
            message: "Error occurred while creating instance",
            error: error.message,
        });
    }
});

When I send a POST request to /getLatandLang, the request hangs and no response is sent. Additionally, the PastWeather instance seems to fail silently. I don’t see any errors in my logs.

const axios = require('axios'); // CommonJS


class pastWeather {
    constructor(locationID) {
        this.locationID = locationID;
    }

    async getData() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/stations/${this.locationID}`, {
                headers: {
                    'token': 'wIYbgYPkGwSUCkoldrbhdvyZoFyAtPpU'
                },
            });

            console.log("Response Data:", response.data);

            const startDate = response.data?.mindate;
            const endDate = response.data?.maxdate;

            if (startDate && endDate) {
                return { startDate, endDate };
            } else {
                console.error("Missing startDate or endDate in response data.");
                return null;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching metadata:", error.response?.data || error.message);
            throw error;
        }
    }

    async getPastWeather(start, end) {
        try {
            let offset = 0;
            const limit = 800;
            let allData = [];

            //while (true) {
                const response = await axios.get('https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data', {
                    headers: {
                        'token': 'wIYbgYPkGwSUCkoldrbhdvyZoFyAtPpU'
                    },
                    params: {
                        stationid: this.locationID,
                        datasetid: 'GSOM',
                        startdate: start,
                        enddate: end,
                        limit: limit,
                        offset: offset
                    }
                });

                const data = response.data?.results || [];
                allData = allData.concat(data);

                
            
            const firstTemps = [];
            const firstPrecip = [];

           
            allData.forEach(item => {
                if (item.datatype === 'PRCP') {
                    const month = item.date.split("T")[0].split("-")[1]; // Extract the month
                    const year = item.date.split("T")[0].split("-")[0]; //Extract year
                    firstPrecip.push({value: item.value, month, year});
                }
                if (item.datatype === 'TAVG') {
                    const month = item.date.split("T")[0].split("-")[1]; // Extract the month
                    const year = item.date.split("T")[0].split("-")[0]; //Extract year
                    firstTemps.push({ value: item.value, month, year }); // Push as an object
                }
            });
            

            return { firstTemps, firstPrecip, location: this.locationID };
        } catch (error) {
            return { firstTemps: [], firstPrecip: [] }; 
        }
    }

    
    async allData() {
        //aggregate temps
        const allMonthlyTempsAgg = [];
        const allMonthlyPrecipAgg = [];

        try {
            //get the start and end dates
            const startAndEnd = await this.getData();

            if (!startAndEnd) {
                console.log("Can't retrieve metadata.");
                return;
            }

            //start and end date
            const { startDate, endDate } = startAndEnd;

            //we instantiate new start and end dates which also exist with the JS calendar library
            let currentStartDate = new Date(startDate);
            const finalEndDate = new Date(endDate);

            while (currentStartDate < finalEndDate) {
                //We first set the endDate to the start date whcih we have
                const currentEndDate = new Date(currentStartDate);
                //We then set the year of the currentEndDate to the full year of the curentEndDate (which is set equal to the start date)
                //+3 in thie case which we set for the endDate here 
                currentEndDate.setFullYear(currentEndDate.getFullYear() + 3);

                //if our currentEndDate is larger than the finalEndDate - we set the time to the finalEndDate
                if (currentEndDate > finalEndDate) {
                    currentEndDate.setTime(finalEndDate.getTime());
                }

                try {
                    //We then pass in an instance of the pastWeather method
                    const blockedData = await this.getPastWeather(
                        //however, within this method we then split with the "T" keyword since accoring to the ISO declarations
                        //out times are typically seen as: "2024-12-17T10:30:00.000Z" and we only want to extract the first bit
                        currentStartDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
                        currentEndDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
                    );

                    //We then add the value of firstTmpes to the allMonthlyTempsAgg using the 
                    //.forEach operator since we're adding each bit from the array which is returned here
                    blockedData.firstTemps.forEach(temp => {
                        allMonthlyTempsAgg.push(temp);
                    });
                    //Similarly - we add each part of the fristPrecip here onto the allMonthlyPrecip and push
                    //it on here 
                    blockedData.firstPrecip.forEach(precip => {
                        allMonthlyPrecipAgg.push(precip);
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error fetching data for range:", error);
                }
                //We then set the currentStartDate to the currentEndDate
                currentStartDate = new Date(currentEndDate);
                currentStartDate.setDate(currentStartDate.getDate() + 1);
            }

            return {
                monthlyInitialTemps: allMonthlyTempsAgg,
                monthlyInitialPrecip: allMonthlyPrecipAgg,
                location: this.locationID
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error in allData:", error.message);
        }
    }

    async parseData() {
        const year = 0;
        try {
            const allData = await this.allData();
        const monthlyTempParsed = Array.from({ length: 12 }, () => []);
        const monthlyPrecipParsed = Array.from({ length: 12 }, () => []);

        //Take full temperature data and parse it into it's monthly temperatures, while also keeping the month and year
        //it's apart of 
        for (let i = 0; i < allData.monthlyInitialTemps.length; ++i) {
            if (allData.monthlyInitialTemps[i] && allData.monthlyInitialTemps[i].value != null) {
                let month = parseInt(allData.monthlyInitialTemps[i].month, 10) - 1; // Transform month to index
                monthlyTempParsed[month].push({
                    value: allData.monthlyInitialTemps[i].value, 
                    year: allData.monthlyInitialTemps[i].year
                });
                
            }
        }
        //Take full precipitation data and parse it into it's monthly precipitation, while also keeping the month and year
        //it's apart of 
        for (let i = 0; i < allData.monthlyInitialPrecip.length; ++i) {
            if (allData.monthlyInitialPrecip[i] && allData.monthlyInitialPrecip[i].value != null) {
                let month = parseInt(allData.monthlyInitialPrecip[i].month, 10) - 1; // Transform month to index
                monthlyPrecipParsed[month].push({
                    value: allData.monthlyInitialPrecip[i].value, 
                    year: allData.monthlyInitialPrecip[i].year
                });
            }
        }
           
            
            const monthlyFinalTemp = Array.from({ length: 12}, () => []);
            const monthlyFinalPrecip = Array.from({ length: 12}, () => []);

            for(let i = 0; i<12; ++i) {
                //FIRST PARSE THE TEMPERATURE DATA
                    let j = 0;
                    while (j < monthlyTempParsed[i].length) {
                        let sum = 0
                        let num = 0;
                        let currentYear = parseInt(monthlyTempParsed[i][j].year, 10);
                        //here we immediatly check that the month is not out of bounds for ALL the months
                        //which were captured
                        while (j < monthlyTempParsed[i].length &&
                            //further - we check after finding if it's out of bounds or not if the year represented
                            //as an int is more than 5 larger or not than currentYear + 5. PART BELOW APART OF TOTAL WHILE LOOP
                            parseInt(monthlyTempParsed[i][j].year, 10) <= currentYear + 5
                        ) {
                            //We then sum the monthlyTemp value here 
                            sum += monthlyTempParsed[i][j].value;

                            //we also increment the value of num
                            num++;
                            //We then increment j to check if it's within our total bounds and if it's within the 5-
                            //year bounds which we were checking before 
                            j++; 
                        }
            
                        // Push the average if there are entries, or else continue with the iteration 
                        if (num > 0) {
                            const average = sum/num;
                            monthlyFinalTemp[i].push(average); // Store the result for this 5-year block

                        }
                    }
                //FIRST PARSE THE TEMPERATURE DATA THE EXACT SAME LOGICAL WAY AS BEFORE
                 let k = 0;
                 while (k < monthlyPrecipParsed[i].length) {
                     let sum = 0
                     let num = 0;
                     let currentYear = parseInt(monthlyPrecipParsed[i][k].year, 10);
                     while (k < monthlyPrecipParsed[i].length &&
                         parseInt(monthlyPrecipParsed[i][k].year, 10) <= currentYear + 5
                     ) {
                         sum += monthlyPrecipParsed[i][k].value;
                         num++;
                         k++; 
                     }
                     if (num > 0) {
                         const average = sum/num;
                         monthlyFinalPrecip[i].push(average); // Store the result for this 5-year block
                    }
                }
            }
            //FOR TESTING ONLY
           // console.log(__dirname);
            return {
                monthlyFinalTemp, monthlyFinalPrecip 
            }
            } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error parsing data" + error);
        }
    }
}

//FOR CommonJS RENDERING ONLY
module.exports = pastWeather;


I have tried taking the instantiation of the class that relies on the API pull outside of the POST request. When instantiated globally (outside any route), the class works as expected, and all subsequent data is retrieved correctly. However, when instantiated within the POST request, the request hangs, and the class fails to initialize or function properly, and my actual website usually times out without any error showing up.

What is this "PastWeather"? Please provide more context, not everyone knows what it is.

It's a Javascript class which I created which pulls data from NOAA.gov database. It works correctly on its own and outside of any node.js rendering routes. I'll also add that instantiating any class fails within the app.post() method

Then you should provide it in your post too. We can guess what's wrong with it just from the name.

Try moving the const PastWeather line out of the function.

@LãNgọcHải I've now added the pastWeather class in

Is this express? Have you configured it to use promises?

No, I am using Axios for this setup, which should have promises already integrated into its system
